# Move dropdown to the right in html/php/css

Tags: php, html, css, dropdown

I have a dropdown that I want to move a bit to the right but the way I'm trying to do it isn't working. Here's my css

```
<head>
    <style>select.indent{ padding-left: 1.8em }</style>
</head>
```

Here's my dropdown code

```
echo    "<select class='indent' name = 'Employee'>";
```

Comment: You can directly use `.indent` in your css code since you already specified indent as a selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to shift the entire select to the right, you should use `margin-left`. Using `padding-left` will just make the dropdown a little wider.

Alternatively you can use relative positioning to move it. Though keep in mind that this just moves where it's being *rendered*, not where the element actually is. This can screw up your formatting if you don't use it properly.

```
select.indent {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px; /* Amount you want it moved by */
}
```

Comment: @Jola If that answered your question can you mark this as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the select element to the right then you could do this:

```
select.indent{ margin-left: 1.8em }
```

or like this:

```
select.indent{ position: relative: left: 1.8em }
```

padding-left will add spacing inside the select dropdown from left